# Vuetify: Add custom hover style to v-btn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm a Beginner in `Vuetify`.
I want to create a button on my website like this:

```
<v-btn class="v-btn white--text mx-1 px-6" elevation="2" x-small rounded color="#BB86FC">text</v-btn>
```

also am adding `<v-hover>` tag to my code:

```
<v-hover>
  <v-btn class="white--text mx-1 px-6" elevation="2" x-small rounded color="#BB86FC">text</v-btn>
</v-hover>
```

and adding style in my `CSS`:

```
.v-btn:hover:
```

but is not working.

How can I give it a different `style` to change the `background color` so when hovering over the button, the color changes to "red"?

Comment: Why you are using `.v-btn` in the css style?

Comment: so sorry ..im adding v-btn class ...edid my question now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `v-slot` on `v-hover` and use it in the `style-binding` of the button as follows:

```js
new Vue({ el:"#app", vuetify: new Vuetify() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<v-app id="app">
   <v-hover v-slot="{ hover }">
     <v-btn 
       class="v-btn white--text mx-1 px-6"
       elevation="2" 
       x-small 
       rounded
       :style="{ 'background-color': hover ? 'red' : '#BB86FC' }"
     >text</v-btn>
   </v-hover>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 4):

Also for v-btn you have just directive color, so you can use code like Majed Badawi wrote but change style to :color="hover ? 'red' : 'blue'"

Answer (score 0):

Let's go a little bit deeper..

[From Vuetify 3:](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/hover/#usage)

> The **v-hover** component provides a simple interface for handling hover states for any component. It is a renderless component that uses the **default slot to provide scoped access to its internal model**; as well as **mouse event listeners to modify it**.

[From Vue.js 3:](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slots)

> As discussed in Render Scope, slot content does not have access to state in the child component. However, **there are cases where it could be useful if a slot's content can make use of data from both the parent scope and the child scope**. To achieve that, we need a way for the child to pass data to a slot when rendering it. In fact, we can do exactly that - **we can pass attributes to a slot outlet just like passing props to a component**.

One implementation example using **Vuetify 3** and **Vue.js 3** would be like so:

```
<v-hover v-slot="{ isHovering, props }">
   <v-btn v-bing="props" :color="isHovering ? red : blue" text="cancel" />
</v-hover>
```

We are restructuring variables from within the `v-hover` component, so that we can use them in the slot from the parent component. The way `v-hover` works is by binding the props to the component it needs to listen to, so that it knows when to generate the hover effect. The `v-slot` is providing a two way binding between the child and parent component through the slot mechanism. So whenever the button is hovered (event) it communicates with `v-hover` through the `props` and `v-hover` reacts by changing the state of `isHovering` and thus changing the color of the button.